# Geoserver shape-zip archive response - setting UTF-8 character encoding for .dbf file?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, geoserver

I created a WPS request to Geoserver, that returns a shapefile as ZIP archive which contains several files, including .shp, .dbf and .cst files.
Data columns in .dbf file are encoded based on the encoding information from .cst file (which is ISO-8859-1).
How can i configure Geoserver, or format WPS xml request, so that response .dbf file is encoded in UTF-8 instad of ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GET request, you can add this to your URL:

```
format_options=CHARSET:UTF-8
```